# How to render a grid element in front or behind an overlapping sibling element using Singularity GS

Tags: singularitygs

Is it possible to specify an overlapping grid element to be rendered in front or behind its siblings?

My code below will render the `.l-branding` div behind the `.l-header`. I need `.l-branding` before `.l-header` in the source order so it renders above `.l-header` (slideshow) on mobiles.

HTML:

```
<div class="l-container">
    <div class="l-branding">
            <!-- logo -->
    </div>                  

    <div class="l-header">
        <!-- image slider -->               
    </div><!-- end .l-header -->

    <navigation class="l-navigation" role="navigation">             
        <!-- navigation -->             
    </navigation>


</div><!-- end .l-container -->
```

SCSS:
I can use `position:absolute;` and `z-index:10` for the `$tab` & `$desk` breakpoints but would like to know if there is a better way.

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// HEADER
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

.l-header-wrap {
    @include clearfix;
}

.l-header {
    @include grid-span(4,1);
    @include breakpoint($tab) {
        @include grid-span(12,1);
        min-height:$vert-spacing-unit * 5;
    }
    @include breakpoint($desk) {
        @include grid-span(18,1);
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//// BRANDING
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


.l-branding {
    @include grid-span(4,1);
    @include breakpoint($tab) {
        @include grid-span(11,1);
        //position: absolute;
        //top:1em;
    }
    @include breakpoint($desk) {
        @include grid-span(17,1);
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//// NAV
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


.l-navigation {
    @include grid-span(4,1);
    @include grid-background;
    @include breakpoint($tab) {
        @include grid-span(12,1);
        //margin-top:-100px;
        //position: absolute;
        //bottom:0;
    }
    @include breakpoint($desk) {
        @include grid-span(18,1);
        //margin-top:-100px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with singularity per se, but it can be done with normal CSS. The answer is what you've already done, absolute positioning and `z-index`. A quick preview of what it would look like is [here on CodePen](http://codepen.io/Snugug/pen/oxCfL).

I'm not entirely sure if even Flexbox will solve this issue, I believe this is something that just needs to be solved using position and z-index as that's what you're asking to do.